# Etags doesn't work for photos call: Users/{userId}/photos/{photoSize}/$value

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Even though request header has: If-None-Match: {{Etag-value}} and response header has the corresponding Etag. It still not working as desired. Instead of getting the response from the server as HTTP 304 Not Modified status, I'm getting the whole response every time i.e., the image value.